# Finding $a_i:U→\mathbb R$ of class $C^{k-1}$ such that $f(x,y)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^ia_j(x,y)x^jy^{i-j}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ of class $C^{k}$ ($i \leq k \leq \infty$) in the convex open $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ containing $(0,0)$. Suppose that $f$ all partial derivatives of order $\leq i$ vanish in $(0,0)$. Prove that there exists functions $a_{0},..., a_{i}: U \to \mathbb{R}$ of class $C^{k-1}$, such that $$f(x,y) = \sum_{j=0}^{i}a_{j}(x,y)x^{j}y^{i-j}. \quad \forall (x,y) \in U$$

I didn't have a good idea to start solving, but I don't want a complete solution, I just want some hints to get started. My professor hint me to use Taylor Formula, I tried to do this, but I couldn't see how to use.

Comment: It looks like a direct consequence of Taylor's theorem.

Comment: @i707107, I know that $\displaystyle f(\alpha + v) = \sum_{0}^{k}\frac{1}{i!}\mathrm{d}^{i}f(\alpha)\cdot v^{i}$ where $\alpha = (x,y)$. My ideia is to connect each $\mathrm{d}^{i}f(\alpha)$ with $a_{i}$, but I couldn't get anything interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider function $g(t) = f(tx,ty)$ with parameter $t\in[0,1]$. We have (since $g(0) = f(0,0) = 0$)
$$
f(x,y) = g(1)-g(0) = \int_0^1g'(t)dt = \int_0^1\left(x\partial_x+y\partial_y\right)f(tx,ty)dt= xc_0(x,y) + yc_1(x,y),
$$
where functions
$$
c_0(x,y) = \int_0^1\partial_xf(tx,ty)dt, \quad c_1(x,y) = \int_0^1\partial_yf(tx,ty)dt.
$$
are of class $C^{k-1}$. Note that we've just proved so-called [Hadamard's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_lemma).

Since all the first partial derivatives of $f$ vanish in zero, $c_0(0,0) = c_1(0,0) = 0$, and we may apply above result to them: 
$$
c_0(x,y) = xc_{00}(x,y) + yc_{01}(x,y), \quad c_1(x,y) = xc_{10}(x,y) + yc_{11}(x,y)
$$
where $c_{ij}$ are function of class $C^{k-2}$. Repeating this procedure $i-1$  times and collecting all the results we'll obtain reminded expansion 
$$
f(x,y) = \sum_{j=0}^{i}C_j(x,y)x^jy^{i-j}, 
$$ 
where $C_j(x,y) = \sum_{|\alpha|=j} c_\alpha(x,y)$ are of class $C^{k-i}$ ($\alpha$ is [multi-index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation) of dim $i$).

Comment: Nice and very well written! Thanks!